# How to install Lean-4 stable only?

Tags: lean, installation, ubuntu, linux

I followed [Lean documentation](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/setup.html) to install Lean 4 on my Ubuntu Linux (20.04 LTS) using the `elan` option described there, and updated it to Lean4 `m3` using:

```
elan self update
elan default leanprover/lean4:stable
elan update
```

I noticed that my Lean folder `~/.elan` is now taking a lot of space (1.5G). Most space is taken by sub-directory is `~/.elan/toolchains`:

```
539M    ./leanprover--lean4---nightly
535M    ./leanprover--lean4---stable
332M    ./leanprover-lean4-stable
31M     ./stable
```

It seems that `elan` installed all three branches of Lean (two of the four are for lean4-stable):

```
$ elan update
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable'
info: latest update on stable, lean version v3.39.2
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly'
info: latest update on nightly, lean version nightly-2022-02-20
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable'
info: latest update on stable, lean version v4.0.0-m3
info: checking for self-updates

                    stable unchanged - Lean (version 3.39.2, commit 402f41cdedbd, Release)
  leanprover/lean4:nightly unchanged - Lean (version 4.0.0-nightly-2022-02-20, commit 7a13eaea8da4, Release)
   leanprover/lean4:stable unchanged - Lean (version 4.0.0, commit d2dcff1f9a20, Release)
```

But I only need one branch - `leanprover/lean4:stable`.

My questions are:

*How can I make sure that elan only installs and updates one branch of Lean4?*

*What is the proper way to remove an unused branch?*
(`elan` does not seems to have a remove command)

Comment: Thanks. I tried both `elan target` and `elan remove`, and `elan` says it's invalid command.

Comment: The correct command is `elan toolchain uninstall`, like in rustup

Comment: @SebastianUllrich Indeed, if you post it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: is there a way to uninstall the`elan`? is that recommended? I was trying to re-ininstall all of lean form scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @SebastianUllrich in the comments:

The command for removing a toolchain is `elan toolchain uninstall branch_name`, like in rustup. ([rustup command examples](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/examples.html))

For example, the following removes the `stable` branch (be sure to replace it with the name of the branch you want to remove!):

```
$ elan toolchain uninstall stable
info: uninstalling toolchain 'stable'
info: toolchain 'stable' uninstalled
```

-- my original answer --:

I just tried the hard way by deleting the directories of the the unused in `~/.elan/toolchains` (after trial and errors) with:

```
rm -rf ./leanprover-lean4-stable ./leanprover--lean4---nightly
```

and then did `elan update` again. It seems that `elan` can recognize and handle the changes, and it only shows the remaining branches after the update:

```
$ elan update
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable'
info: latest update on stable, lean version v3.39.2
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable'
info: latest update on stable, lean version v4.0.0-m3
info: checking for self-updates

                   stable unchanged - Lean (version 3.39.2, commit 402f41cdedbd, Release)
  leanprover/lean4:stable unchanged - Lean (version 4.0.0, commit d2dcff1f9a20, Release)
```

The other branches do not show up again.

Comment: is there a way to uninstall the`elan`? is that recommended? I was trying to re-ininstall all of lean form scratch.