# What is the official way to reinstall Lean4 from scratch on a Mac or Linux?

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-community

I want to install Lean from scratch to see if I can fix [a previous issue related to the location where I can create lean projects](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/how-does-one-create-a-lean-project-and-have-mathlib-import-work-when-not-creatin) [(and a related issue).](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/how-does-one-create-a-lean-project-even-if-it-already-exists-e-g-lake-leanpro)

The official instructions don't seem to make it super clear how to re-install lean (or uninstall it). Given there are several (mysterious to me) tools for lean like `elan`, `lake`, `lake-toolchains` and perhaps others I am not aware -- I was hoping for an approved way to uninstall lean as if I were trying to install it from scratch.

I see [I can run](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/macos.html#installing-lean-4):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/master/scripts/install_macos.sh)" && source ~/.profile
```

which requests my trust, which I'm fine to give but worried I might create a worse mess impossible to fix.

alternatively I can [re-run the install commands blindly and hope it works:](https://leanprover-community.github.io/install/macos_details.html#installing-elan-and-mathlib-supporting-tools)

> Installing elan and mathlib supporting tools  Install Homebrew if you
> do not already have it installed.
>
> Run brew install elan-init in a terminal window to install elan.
>
> Note that Homebrew also contains a formula named simply lean, but that
> it installs a fixed version of Lean, rather than one provisioned with
> elan as per the above. Using this formula is as mentioned not
> recommended.
>
> Use elan to install the latest stable version of lean by running elan
> toolchain install stable. You can also set the newly-installed version
> to be the default version of lean you get when running outside of a
> project (discussed below) by running elan default stable.

however all seem hacky with potential issues. Any better recommendations? The ideal algorithm I think would be:

1. uninstall all of lean properly (including all tools e.g. `lake`, `elan`, `lake-toolchains` etc) -- without uninstalling my vscode
2. then re-run the lean install code from scratch, e.g., `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/master/scripts/install_macos.sh)" && source ~/.profile`

suggestions on how to do this?

---

###### What does the official install script `install_mac.sh` do?

here is a detailed commented version of it, [it actually seems quite safe/sensible to execute](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/master/scripts/install_macos.sh):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Shebang line to specify the script should be run with bash

set -exo pipefail
# Set bash options:
# -e: Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
# -x: Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
# -o pipefail: Causes a pipeline to return the exit status of the last command in the pipe that failed.

# Install Homebrew
if ! which brew > /dev/null; then
    # Checks if Homebrew is not installed by attempting to locate the `brew` command and redirects output to /dev/null
    # Install Homebrew
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
    # If Homebrew is not installed, it executes the Homebrew installation script downloaded from GitHub
else
    # Update it, in case it has been ages since it's been updated
    brew update
    # If Homebrew is already installed, update it to the latest version
fi

brew install elan-init
# Install elan, the Lean version manager, using Homebrew

elan toolchain install stable
# Install the latest stable version of the Lean toolchain using elan

elan default stable
# Set the installed stable version of Lean as the default version

# Install and configure VS Code
if ! which code > /dev/null; then
    # Checks if VS Code is not installed by attempting to locate the `code` command and redirects output to /dev/null
    brew install --cask visual-studio-code
    # If VS Code is not installed, install it using Homebrew Cask
fi

# Install the Lean4 VS Code extension
code --install-extension leanprover.lean4
# Installs the Lean4 extension for Visual Studio Code using the `code` command
```

---

related:

- [How to install Lean-4 stable only?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/745/how-to-install-lean-4-stable-only)

Comment: Note before you start removing stuff that I have answered your previous question.

Comment: fyi it seems to be that the real issue I have is a vscode issue https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2766/1199 though it would still be nice to know how to reinstall vscode properly.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect (from your [other question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/how-does-one-create-a-lean-project-and-have-mathlib-import-work-when-not-creatin)) that you're asking this because you believe you have things set up incorrectly, but hopefully my answer to your other question shows you that your set-up is fine and the misundersanding was elsewhere.

However there's no reason not to answer this question anyway, and I personally would say that the official way to uninstall Lean on mac/linux is just to remove the `~/.elan` directory (and, if you like, remove `$HOME/.elan/bin` from `$PATH`), and the official way to remove all the versions of mathlib which you've collected along the way is to remove the `~/.cache/mathlib` directory. Note also that any lean project you have which depends on mathlib is also taking up around 5 gigs of disc space.